# Javascript - fade elements with click

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, opacity

I want to change the opacity in an ul li list after I clicked an element. The clicked element has to stay in opacity:1 and the rest should fade out to opacity:0.3.
After I click an other element, this one should have 1 and the rest 0.3 and so on.

I tried the following code but It didn't worked as I wanted:

```
$(this).toggle(function(){
            $(this).siblings().animate({opacity:0.3}, 1000);
        }, function() {
            $(this).siblings().stop().animate({opacity:1}, 1000);
        });
```

I even tried each() too, didn't helped. Where I am stuck ?

My HTML:

```
<div class="tracklist">
            <div class="left">
                <ul>
                    <li class="one" id="t01"></li>
                    <li class="two"></li>
                    <li class="three"></li>
                    <li class="four"></li>
                    <li class="five"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="right"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Post it as an answer pls!

Answer (score 2):

You can animate the li's as follows:

```js
$("ul li").on("click", function(){
    $(this).animate({"opacity": "1"});
    $(this).siblings().animate({"opacity": "0.3"});    
});
```

```css
li {
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #aaf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="one" id="t01">textA</li>
    <li class="two">textB</li>
    <li class="three">textC</li>
    <li class="four">textD</li>
    <li class="five">textE</li>
</ul>
```